# Component doesn't update the value after call webService in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-0.46

I Called the GET webService in React Native, Its get Successfully response. But I want to set this response in Component. its means according to response the component doesn't update. See my code.

**GET REQUEST :**

```
 makeRemoteRequest = () => {
   this.setState({ loading: true });
   fetch('http://jsonstub.com/ws/pendingInvoices', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'JsonStub-User-Key': 'daf0e17a-5951-49e0-8d32-4cb4bb804577',
        'JsonStub-Project-Key': '4e70b1a8-12d0-4fa5-8c34-a99b666bd073',
      }
    })
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then(res => {

       console.log('Data Is : ' ,res);
       this.setState({
         text : res,
         customData : res,
         error: res.error || null,
         loading: false,
         refreshing: false
       });
     })
     .catch(error => {
       console.log('error Is : ' ,error);
       this.setState({ error, loading: false });
     });
 };
```

**Service Called :**

```
 componentDidMount() {
   this.makeRemoteRequest();
 }
```

**Want To Update text and Accordion**,

```
render(){
       const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        return (
          <View style = {styles.scrollSty}>
               <Accordion
                  sections={this.state.customData}
                  renderHeader={this._renderHeader.bind(this)}
                  renderContent={this._renderContent.bind(this)}
                />
              <View><Text style = {{color : 'white'}}>{this.state.text}</Text></View>

         </View>
        );
     }
    }
```

Comment: do `console.log('render')` inside render method and check whether it's getting called after response or not, *one suggestions*: Instead of doing multiple setState update all the values in one shot.

Comment: The Api response will get successfully.

Comment: No, Thats doesn't call after success response. Only one time Called.

Comment: Where do you put your WebService call ?

Comment: Why do you call setState 3 times in a row?

Comment: @Mayank Shukla , I Called service in componentDidMount.

Comment: are you getting any error message? check console.

Comment: @Mayank Shukla, No any error message. after webservice response, render method doesn't call.

Comment: has this line been called `console.log('Data Is : ' ,res);`? add `this.forceUpdate()` in callback to see the updated result, I know this is not good practice, just for a test.

Comment: Okey. I WILL TRY..

Comment: @Harlan this.forceUpdate() is working, but what is good way.

Comment: if `forceUpdate()` works, I think you can check these: did you initialize your component state in the constructor? did you override method `shouldComponentUpdate()`?

Comment: Yes, I will initialize customData and text in constructor. but what to do with shouldComponentUpdate

Comment: @Harlan, Ya I will not put shouldComponentUpdate , So that may be not working. now solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya. Finally Get the solution : Here we can update the component using two ways.

1. Forceful Update : Call the function after set the values.

   ```
     this.setState({
        customData: customData,
        ...
      });
      this.forceUpdate()
   ```
2. Calling shouldComponentUpdate : if you don't call then doesn't update.

   ```
     shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
       return true;
     }
   ```

Answer (score -2):

I assume you need to bind your `makeRemoteRequest` method in the component's constructor.

```
class YourComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.makeRemoteRequest = this.makeRemoteRequest.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.makeRemoteRequest()
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you initializing your state then?

Comment: Are you sure you don't need to initialize your state in the constructor?